# Convert Crystal Formula Workshop to SQL & SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, crystal-reports

On my first time trying to re-create reports in SSRS taking Crystal Reports, I've been stuck in one Formula to place it in SSRS.

So, how can I convert this `crystal-query-formula` to a `SQL query`?

```
 StringVar DorF:='D';

 if {TABLE.COUNTRY_COLUMN} = 'US' then DorF := 'D';
 if {TABLE.COUNTRY_COLUMN} <> 'US' and not ISNULL 
 ({TABLE.COUNTRY_COLUMN}) then DorF := 'F';
 DorF "
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used Crystal reports but this looks like it can just be a **CASE** statement in a query. I'm not sure about the ELSE though - I think it would be **DorF** which is originally **D**.

```
CASE WHEN COUNTRY_COLUMN = 'US' THEN 'D' 
     WHEN COUNTRY_COLUMN <> 'US' AND COUNTRY_COLUMN IS NOT NULL THEN 'F' 
     ELSE 'D' --??
END
```

If you wanted to do it in SSRS in the report instead of the query, I would use nested **IIF** statements.

```
IIF(Fields!COUNTRY_COLUMN.Value = 'US', "D", 
    IIF(Fields!COUNTRY_COLUMN.Value <> 'US' AND NOT ISNOTHING(Fields!COUNTRY_COLUMN.Value), "F", "D")
```

This reads as `IF country = US then D else if country <> US and NOT NULL then F else D.`

I'm guessing that the field can just be **F**oreign or **D**omestic and no other values.